# C# Word.Interop Change text of ContentControl DropDownList

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to change of a ContentControl using Word.Interop. It works with a ContentControl of Type Text. But it fails with a ContentControl of type wdContentControlDropdownList.
Error message something like "You are not allowed to change because the field is protected".

Is there any way to change the active item of a DropDownList?

```
private void setstatus(string status)
{
    ContentControls ccList;
    ccList = this.activeDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Status");
    ContentControl cc = ccList[1];
    // works with wdContentControlText
    // fails with wdContentControlDropdownList
    cc.Range.Text = status;
}
```

Comment: *Caveat: I know nothing of c# but dabble at vba in Word.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol.dropdownlistentries does not explain how to change an entry, unfortunately. SelectContentControlsByTitle returns a selection, not a range. The way I would approach this would be to delete the current entry and then add a new one in its place.

Comment: If found a strange workaraound. Changing type to wdContentControlRichText, update text in the range object, changing type back to wdContentControlDropdownList. The DropDownList has still all items afterwards.

Comment: You should edit your question to add this information or post as an Answer. People often do not see comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a working solution.

```
private void setstatus(string value)
{
    ContentControls ccList;
    ccList = activeDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Status");
    ContentControl cc = ccList[1];
    // search all list entries and select the required item
    foreach (ContentControlListEntry ccl in cc.DropdownListEntries)
    {
        if (ccl.Text == value)
        {
           ccl.Select();
           break;
        }
    }
}
```